# PgBouncer and idle connections

Tags: php, postgresql, database-administration, pgbouncer

I'm trying to scale my infrastructure.

There is a Php 7.4 app which uses persistent connections.

There is a PgBouncer which the app connects to with the default parameters.

```
/pgbouncer.ini

[databases]
XXXXXXX

[pgbouncer]
listen_addr = 0.0.0.0
listen_port = 4040
unix_socket_dir =
user = postgres
auth_file = /etc/pgbouncer/userlist.txt
auth_type = md5
ignore_startup_parameters = extra_float_digits
logfile = /var/log/pgbouncer/pgbouncer.log
# Log settings
admin_users = postgres
```

And a standard PostgreSQL in a cloud environnement.

I am facing a strange problem where when I load test the app with 50 users ( I am currently testing on small servers in a dev environnement ) a lot are facing this error:

```
pg_query(): Query failed: ERROR: query_wait_timeout server closed the connection unexpectedly
```

In facts, when I use `SHOW POOLS` in PgBouncer here it what it shows:

```
       database       |         user         | cl_active | cl_waiting | sv_active | sv_idle | sv_used | sv_tested | sv_login | maxwait | maxwait_us | pool_mode
----------------------+----------------------+-----------+------------+-----------+---------+---------+-----------+----------+---------+------------+-----------
 XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX | XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX |        20 |         31 |        20 |       0 |       0 |         0 |        0 |     120 |     106966 | session
 pgbouncer            | pgbouncer            |         1 |          0 |         0 |       0 |       0 |         0 |        0 |       0 |          0 | statement
```

This explains the errors, because there are too much waiting clients. But here is the funny thing, at the exact same time ( multiple time in facts to be sure ) I ran the following query on the targeted PostgreSQL:

```
SELECT *
FROM pg_stat_activity
ORDER BY pid desc;
```

What I saw is a bunch of idle clients, and sometimes one / two / three of them showing as active an processing queries ... ! I expected all the 20 clients to be working to serve all the waiting PgBouncer clients ..

( And the idle ones stay idle between 10 to 20secondes before going active )

[image]

Also, it is important to mention that all the servers were at 30% CPU 20% RAM so, it seems (?) this is not a resources issue.

Any ideas of what is going wrong ? I think something is not normal.

Comment: It sounds like your app is not returning connections to the pool fast enough, but rather is holding onto them while doing other time consuming stuff (or just forgetting about them altogether).  There is no way to know why that is with just the info you provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved, it appears php's persistent connections don't work well with PgBouncer. Just turn off persistent connections and everything will run smoothly. :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is session **pooling** mode.
If it was **transaction** or **statement**, it will give no problem.

If session mode is on, every new client connection to pgbouncer takes it's own connection from pgbouncer to databse.
Persistent connection is **persistent connection**, so if there 50 php-fpm workers and every worker connects persistently to pgbouncer, there will be 50 connected clients all the time.

**When connected client is more that maximum possible server connections in session-mode pooling, everything stucks**.

You need to increase server connections pool or switch to transaction/statement mode.
Personally, I'd propose switch on persistent because it's decreases time for application-to-database connection.